# PE Sections Permissions

Tags: windows, pe

I wanted to know which permissions each section of the following PE Sections have (windows):

```
.idata
.rsrc
.data
.text
.bss
.rdata
.edata
```

Thanks in advance, I couldn't  found an answer using google. :)

Comment: why not take any PE file and look at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the official PE-format documentation [here.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19509)

The section permissions are completely up to the programmer / compiler. You can parse the permissions out of the sections table. Please know that the permissions may be changed at runtime and also may be manipulated for smaller units of memory (pages!).

That being said, there is always some 'default' permissions set by the compiler if the programmer doesn't care about them explicitly:

For example, the `.text` section is usually `READ + EXECUTE`, while data sections are usually `READ + WRITE (+ PROTECTED)`. There is no magic here.

There is plenty of software available to look at the startup section permissions (basically everything parsing pe files).

Comment: So by that I can understand everything i asked except .rsrc, which I dont know if I can call data. What do you think?

Comment: the .rsrc section contains all ressources compiled into the binary (icons etc.). Since Windows allows updating resources, I assume they are frequently flagged READ + WRITE

Answer (score 3):

You can use DUMPBIN for examining section permissions. If you run it with no other argument than executable name it shows sections in executable.

```
C:\> dumpbin ConsoleApplication1.exe
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.10.24930.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file ConsoleApplication1.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

  Summary

    1000 .data
    1000 .rdata
    1000 .reloc
    1000 .rsrc
    1000 .text
```

Then, check for specific section:

```
C:\> dumpbin /SECTION:.text ConsoleApplication1.exe
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.10.24930.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file ConsoleApplication1.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

SECTION HEADER #1
   .text name
     C2F virtual size
    1000 virtual address (00401000 to 00401C2E)
     E00 size of raw data
     400 file pointer to raw data (00000400 to 000011FF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
60000020 flags
         Code
         Execute Read <----

  Summary

        1000 .text
```

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>dumpbin c:\Windows\System32\calc.e
xe /headers | grep SECTION -A 14 |  grep -A 3 flags
60000020 flags
         Code
         Execute Read

--
C0000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Read Write

--
40000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Read Only

--
42000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Discardable
         Read Only

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>
```